# BigQuery ASCII 0 Error even with ASCII only characters

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery, ascii

I am trying to load a pandas dataframe to a bigquery table , but I get the ASCII 0 error. I know for a fact, the text only contains ascii characters, and the issue is with only one column only (unclear which row, however). I have tried the following:

1. pandas dataframe from API call to BQ table results in  ASCII 0 error
2. saved dataframe as a csv in google cloud storage (from API call), upload manually to BQ table results in ASCII 0 error
3. download csv from google cloud storage onto local drive, upload manually to BQ table results in ASCII 0 error
4. BUT if i take the file in step 3, resave the file, and then upload manually to BQ table, it uploads without issue

I am unsure why step 4 would work and not the others. The data frame only contains two columns, so it is not a matter of other columns that may contain non-ascii characters. I have narrowed it down to the culprit column.

Error:

```
0it [00:00, ?it/s]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 629, in load_data
    for remaining_rows in chunks:
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1081, in __iter__
    for obj in iterable:
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/load.py", line 82, in load_chunks
    location=location,
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 734, in result
    return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py", line 134, in result
    raise self._exception
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 39540. Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/document_download_20201223_dd87eec0/wd_download.py", line 268, in <module>
    obj.clean_data()
  File "/tmp/document_download_20201223_dd87eec0/wd_download.py", line 248, in clean_data
    self.res_df.to_gbq(datatable,project_id,if_exists='replace')
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1657, in to_gbq
    credentials=credentials,
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/gbq.py", line 228, in to_gbq
    private_key=private_key,
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 1210, in to_gbq
    progress_bar=progress_bar,
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 636, in load_data
    self.process_http_error(ex)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas_gbq/gbq.py", line 435, in process_http_error
    raise GenericGBQException("Reason: {0}".format(ex))
pandas_gbq.gbq.GenericGBQException: Reason: 400 Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 39540. Error: Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered.

0it [00:02, ?it/s]
Job output is complete
```

Code for method 1:

```
self.res_df['clean'] = self.res_df['clean'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'',x))
self.res_df['clean'] = self.res_df['clean'].apply(lambda x: bytes(x, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
self.res_df.to_gbq(datatable,project_id,if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: if you two file - correct and wrong - then you could use some program to compare them. Or you could write script which compare bytes values and display them - this way maybe it shows what value makes problem. Maybe when it save wrong file then it adds BOM (Byte Order Mark) which uses values `\xff` `\xfe`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but both files are exactly the same. I dont think BOM is the issue because this problem exists even when trying to load a DF in memory to BQ (i.e., it is never saved at any point)